# Move/rewrite a txt file that matches a string in a folder with multiple txt files

Tags: python, search, text, move

I'm trying to use python to search for a string in a folder which contains multiple .txt files. 
My objective is to find those files containing the string and move/or re-write them in another folder. 
what I have tried is:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir('./*.txt'):   
    if os.path.isfile(filename):    
        with open(filename) as f:   
            for line in f:  
            if 'string/term to be searched' in line:
                f.write
                break
```

probably there is something wrong with this but, of course, cannot figure it out.

Comment: What happens? What should happen?

Comment: and: `f.write` should be `f.write(something)` with `something` being a string you want to write in the file.

Answer (score 1):

[os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) argument must be a path, not a pattern. You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to accomplish that task:

```
import os
import glob

for filename in glob.glob('./*.txt'):   
    if os.path.isfile(filename):    
        with open(filename) as f:   
            for line in f:  
                if 'string/term to be searched' in line:
                    # You cannot write with f, because is open in read mode
                    # and must supply an argument.
                    # Your actions 
                    break
```

Answer (score 1):

As Antonio says, you cannot write with f because it is open in read mode.
A possible solution to avoid the problem is the following:

```
import os
import shutil

source_dir = "your/source/path"
destination_dir = "your/destination/path"


for top, dirs, files in  os.walk(source_dir):
    for filename in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(top, filename)
        check = False
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            if 'string/term to be searched' in f.read():
                check = True
        if check is True:
            shutil.move(file_path, os.path.join(destination_dir , filename))
```

Remember that if your source_dir or destination_dir contains some "special characters" you have to put the double back-slash.

For example, this:

```
source_dir = "C:\documents\test"
```

should be

```
source_dir = "C:\documents\\test"
```